# Como generar Codigo de Barra GS1 en .Net Framework 4.0 c#

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy necesitando generar códigos de barra GS1 en C# .Net 4.0

Cualquier ayuda seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Tu pregunta es demasiado escueta, deberías añadir algo de información sobre qué has averiguado investigando, o algún trozo de código con algún intento que hayas hecho. Tal como está ahora difícilmente podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Buenas, ¿sobre que irían tus códigos de barras? algún reporte _crystal report_, o como piensas imprimirlo?

Answer (score 2):

creo que lo que buscas es una librería para generar los codigos de barra.

para eso existe: http://barcoderender.codeplex.com

el codigo puede ser generado de dos formas:

1. codificando e imprimiendo en un tipo de fuente especial: http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/documentation
2. la segunda forma es renderizar el código a una imagen y usar esa imagen de cualquier forma que la necesites.

Comment: Creo que esa libreria no tiene soporte para GS1 que es lo que pide Pedro

Comment: @jasilva existe el GS1-128, el cual es una aplicación del GS usando el Code 128 como fuente. doc: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128

Comment: Gracias desconocia ese dato